# ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType is deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart

After Flutter version 1.12.1 `ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType` is deprecated. 
We should use `getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType` now.  
How do I edit this `BlocProvider` to work with this new method?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Type _typeOf<T>() => T;

abstract class BlocBase {
  void dispose();
}

class BlocProvider<T extends BlocBase> extends StatefulWidget {
  BlocProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;
  final T bloc;

  @override
  _BlocProviderState<T> createState() => _BlocProviderState<T>();

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>();
    _BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
        context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget; //deprecated
    return provider?.bloc;
  }
}

class _BlocProviderState<T extends BlocBase> extends State<BlocProvider<T>> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _BlocProviderInherited<T>(
      bloc: widget.bloc,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class _BlocProviderInherited<T> extends InheritedWidget {
  _BlocProviderInherited({
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);
  final T bloc;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_BlocProviderInherited oldWidget) => false;
}
```

Do I get rid of the `_typeOf` variable now? 
What are the benefits of this change?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>().widget` and it should work.

As far as benefits go, the documentation basically states the same though someone can correct me but I don't see any difference. You should be able to get rid of the `_typeOf` variable.

Comment: When using context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>().widget;  I get the Error: .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dynamic_theme-1.0.1/lib/dynamic_theme.dart:25:20: Error: The method 'ancestorStateOfType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
     - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorStateOfType'.

Comment: @Benjamin In the latest version of Flutter this getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType method was deprecated and it was mentioned to replace it with findAncestorWidgetOfExactType. If we do the same then the code snippet was looking like this

static T of<T extends Bloc>(BuildContext context) {
    var provider = context
        .findAncestorWidgetOfExactType<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>();
    _BlocProviderInherited<T> widget = provider;
    return widget?.bloc;
  }

Does the above code will work to share the bloc instance to all his child widgets in Navigation stack